# Powershell Update Multiple Users attribute from CSV file

Tags: powershell

trying to load attribute [Pager] for users using CSV file with below script, but actually doesn't process it , not sure what might be the reason. running on my lab as domain admin.

```
Function Update-ADUsers { 
$csvfile = "C:\Powershell\pager\users.csv"
Import-Csv -path $csvfile

ForEach-Object {  
  $sam = $_.'Logon Name' 
{{ Set-ADUser -Identity $sam -Replace @{pager="http://server/users/"+ $sam +".jpg"} }} 
$pager="http://server/users/"+ $sam +".jpg"
Write-Host "$pager"
Write-Host "$sam"
}}

Update-ADUsers
```

it's simple CSV file as content following:

```
Logon Name
mahmoud
ahmed
hussien
ayman
```

> Latest Working fine now

```
Function Update-ADUsers {
    $csvfile = "C:\Powershell\pager\users.csv" 
    Import-Csv -path $csvfile |
    ForEach-Object {
        $sam = $_.'Name' 
        $pager = "http://server/users/" + $sam + ".jpg"
        Get-ADUser -Filter "sAMAccountName -eq '$sam'" | Set-ADUser -Replace @{pager=$pager}
        Write-Host "$pager"
        Write-Host "$sam" 
    }
}
Update-ADUsers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aside from not posting the question in the code block so it's obfuscating any additional formatting errors, you have your `Set-ADUser` call wrapped in double curly braces unnecessarily and are setting variables in odd places. Here's what I adjusted it to:

```
Function Update-ADUsers {
    $csvfile = "C:\Powershell\pager\users.csv" 
    Import-Csv -path $csvfile | ForEach-Object {
        $sam = $_.'Logon Name' 
        $pager = "http://server/users/" + $sam + ".jpg"
        Set-ADUser -Identity $sam -Replace @{pager=$pager}
        Write-Host "$pager"
        Write-Host "$sam" 
    }
}
Update-ADUsers
```

** As an aside, is your full logon name that you're trying to use for `-Identity` "mahmoud ahmed hussien ayman"? If so, you need to use either the SamAccountName, distinguishedName, or pass in an AD User object. If that is the **name** of the user object, you can find it like this then pipe it into your `Set-ADUser` call:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "name -eq '$sam'" | Set-ADUser -Replace @{pager=$pager}
```

Comment: There is a vertical bar/pipe symbol `|` missing at the end of the line `Import-Csv -path $csvfile` ForEach needs something to iterate over.

Comment: yes trying to user sAMAccountName , but i guess there's problem getting in reading from CSV file as showing following error. [Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized
At line:7 char:9
+         Get-ADUser -Filter "sAMAccountName -eq '$sam'" | Set-ADUser -Replace @{p ...
]

Comment: @LotPings that's right that solved my issue, thnx alot :) sorry for any inconvenience caused i'm still new here. thnx guys for help.

Comment: ahhhh @LotPings --- saw that and completely focused on the formatting, then missed the update... cheers!

Comment: @mostafa -- if possible, please format code as a code block when posting questions so it's a little easier to read ;-)... updated my answer to include the pipe between `Import-Csv` & `ForEach-Object`